# phoneGap console.log ubuntu

Tags: android, cordova, debugging

I'm new in phoneGap and have problem to debug my app, I know that exist a lot of post about this but really I don't have idea how make this work.

I have `console.log("message")` in severals part of my code; but how can see this message when run my app?

I use this command to run

```
phonegap build android 
phonegap run android --target=G7T7N16A26000893 --debug
```

with this result

[image]

with this not terminal still open to see anything. Aditional I try with Chroome DevsTools; but look that is only for pages not for apps.

Comment: Chrome can inspect your app; navigate to "chrome://inspect". Make sure your device allows USB debugging as well and is connected.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Kerri Shotts you are rigth, with google in remote devices could see apps, full tutorial [her](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3#debugging-webviews)